# How to disable the "function lock" key on a cheap keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys, ps2

I recently inherited a cheap no-name keyboard and it feels a lot better to type on than the cheap Trust keyboard I previously had. However, there's a huge problem with it that I don't like: it has a button that works like a function lock button - when it's on (the default), F1 through F12 are disabled and instead triggers special functions like Help and Open.

As someone who works in an IDE a lot, this means I can't do things like use F3 to search through a file *without* first remembering to press the key after *every* reboot. I've forgotten to press it so many times that I'm now considering going back to my old keyboard unless I can get this sorted.

Is there a way I can permanently enable this key or completely circumvent it so that the function keys always work, or am I going to have to switch back to my old keyboard? I would prefer something that was more robust than a software solution, although will take one if there's no alternative.

Comment: Can you provide details on the exact model of keyboard? Perhaps a picture?

Comment: @Hashim Please specify your Operating system and its release number,, essential information, for this website helps many people with many different OS.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I didn't even expect it to have a model number, but turns out it's an all-black version of [this model](https://www.cnet.com/products/anyware-ez-8000-smart-office-keyboard-black-silver/).

Comment: See if it can be set to default to pressed in BIOS.